# Append multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this a basic question but I don't know what to do. I have been stuck on this from hours but I don't know what is wrong with it.

**what I want to do:**
I want to append input field when user click on button(simple!).

**Problem:** It only append one time only.

[**This is my fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1776/)

**Html code:**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="tab_logic">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="text-center">#</th>
       <th class="text-center">Name</th>
       <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr id='addr0'></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <button id='add' class="btn btn-outline btn-default">Add</button>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
var i=0;
    $('#add').click( function() {
      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      $('#addr'+(i+1)).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>"+
      "<td><input type='text' class='form-control input-md' /></td>"+
      "<td><input type='text'  class='form-control input-md'></td>"+
      "<td><a class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='deleterow(this)' class'delete'></a></td>" 
      );  
    });
    
      function deleterow(obj){
        $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
      }
```

Sorry I know Its very basic question but my JavaScript is weak.

Comment: You dont count `i` up

Comment: A few tips: Use the existing row count (or last id) etc to determine the next id number to generate. Also use single quotes for the outer strings, that that the HTML attributes have double-quotes (for browser compatibility). Also consider using a dummy/template element instead of HTML string concatenation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1777/

```
var i=0;
    $('#add').click( function() {
      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      $('#addr'+(i+1)).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>"+
      "<td><input type='text' class='form-control input-md' /></td>"+
      "<td><input type='text'  class='form-control input-md'></td>"+
      "<td><a class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='deleterow(this)' class'delete'></a></td>");  
      i++;
});
```

You don't increment i after you click

Comment: I don't know how i forget that i have done this thousand time.

Comment: @The Real Hamza: You mean 1001 times ;)

Comment: Aside from the increment, the generated HTML in strings is also not correct: e.g. `class'delete'`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to increment variable `i`:

```
i++
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1781/

Comment: You probably didn't save your last jsfiddle change, there is no `i++` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your javascript a little bit to work:

```
var i=0;
    $('#add').click( function() {
      i += 1;
      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i)+'"></tr>');
      $('#addr'+(i)).html("<td>"+ (i) +"</td>"+
      "<td><input type='text' class='form-control input-md' /></td>"+
      "<td><input type='text'  class='form-control input-md'></td>"+
      "<td><a class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='deleterow(this)' class'delete'></a></td>" 
      );  
    });

      function deleterow(obj){
        $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
      }
```

variable `i` is defined as global variable, while in your method, you are not increasing its value. That was the issue.

Here is the update fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1784/

Answer (score 2):

everytime i value is 0 and i+1 is always 1. add `i=i+1;` to your code.

Please find below code

```
$('#add').click( function() {debugger;
  $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
  $('#addr'+(i+1)).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>"+
  "<td><input type='text' class='form-control input-md' /></td>"+
  "<td><input type='text'  class='form-control input-md'></td>"+
  "<td><a class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='deleterow(this)' class'delete'></a></td>" 
  );
  i=i+1;                           
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise there are already 4 answers, but I would like to demonstrate the tips I mentioned in comment for creating simple code that is easier to maintain.

Also your HTML concatenation is actually not quite right, but nobody can tell with all the string operations.

- Use the existing row count (or last id) etc to determine the next id number to generate.
- Consider using a dummy/template element instead of HTML string concatenation. This allows for maintainable templates.
- Use single quotes for the outer strings, that that the HTML attributes have double-quotes (for browser compatibility).

This example has the first two as the quotes issue goes away:

### JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1787/

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var count = $('#tab_logic tr').length;
    $('#tab_logic').append($('#template').html().replace(/{i}/g, count));
});

function deleterow(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
    return false;
}
```

In this example your template row sits in a dummy script block (of unknown type so is ignored). It uses a "global" replace option in a regex to replace all occurrences of a placeholder with the desired value(s).

Comment: thanks it really help me and i will keep that in mind. and I would have chose your answer but i have selected a answer.

Comment: You are allowed to change your "answer" at any time, but that is up to you. I just wanted to pass on those tips for nicer code. :)